# Netty and RTP - worse than plain old DatagramSockets?

Tags: java, netty, rtp

I'm trying to optimize an RTP server to be able to handle more RTP endpoints. For handling the RTP part I originally used librtp however I also came up with a librtp variant that uses Netty instead of plain old `DatagramSocket`:

```
io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket nettyDatagramPacket = new io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket(data, socketAddress);
        ChannelFuture future = channel.writeAndFlush(nettyDatagramPacket);
```

However it seems my approach is actually slower:
[image: Histogram of RTP intervals when using Netty transport]

[image: Histogram of RTP intervals when using DatagramSocket]

Both graphs show the RTP packet intervals as measured by Wireshark and on the right a typical RTP interval diagram as drawn by Wireshark (over time).

**Is it possible Netty is not suited for timing sensitive IO operations due to the fact that the sending is offloaded to another thread?**

I assume because with Netty the sending is de-coupled from the packet generation (which happens every 20ms) it might occur that multiple packets (even for the same stream) are bunched together and sent pretty much without delay. Is there a Netty way to improve this? Right now I'm using the default thread pools offered by Netty!